# Copying Hive managed table by copying partition directories into warehouse

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hql, hadoop-partitioning

I have an existing bucketed table that has `YEAR, MONTH, DAY` partitioning, but I want to add additional partitioning by `INGESTION_KEY`, a column that doesn't exist in the existing table. This is to accommodate future table inserts so that I don't have to `OVERWRITE` a `YEAR, MONTH, DAY` partition every time I ingest data for that date; I can just do a simple `INSERT INTO` and create a new  `INGESTION_KEY` partition.

I need a year's worth of data in my new table to start, so I want to copy a year of partitions from my existing table to a new table. Rather than doing a Hive `INSERT` for each partition, I thought it would be quicker to use `distcp` to copy files into the new table's partition directories in the Hive warehouse directory in HDFS, then `ADD PARTITION` to the new table.

So, this is all I'm doing:

```
hadoop distcp /apps/hive/warehouse/src_db.db/src_tbl/year=2017/month=02/day=06 /apps/hive/warehouse/dest_db.db/dest_tbl/year=2017/month=02/day=06/ingestion_key=123

hive -e "ALTER TABLE dest_tbl ADD PARTITION (year=2017,month=02,day=06,ingestion_key='123')"
```

Both are managed tables, the new table `dest_tbl` is clustered by the same column into the same number of buckets as the `src_tbl`, and the only difference in schema is the addition of `INGESTION_KEY`.

So far my `SELECT * FROM dest_tbl` shows everything in the new table looking normal. So my question is: is there anything wrong with this approach? Is it bad to `INSERT` to a managed, bucketed table this way, or is this an acceptable alternative to `INSERT` if no transformations are being done on the copied data?

Thanks!!

Comment: You should not think in terms of `INSERT`, rather in terms of backup/restore operations. The Hive metastore does not keep trace of the data files, only of the directory structure; so as long as the file structure match the metadata, it's fair.

Comment: BTW it's also a convenient way to sample Production data and ship it to a Test or QA cluster...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although i prefer copying by Hive query just to make it all in Hive, but it's ok to copy data files using other tools, but ..

- There is a dedicated command that add the new partitions metadata, you can use it in place of `alter table add partition..`, and it can add many partitions at once :

  ```
  MSCK REPAIR TABLE dest_tbl;
  ```
- Keep using Hive default partitioning format : `partionKey=partitionValue`